# Can we automatically stack images into one tall image with Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

photoshop has a feature that allows us to stack images into layers in one file. Can we automatically apply the height of the new image as the sum of all layers and then spread the layers to make one very tall image? For example like this:

[image: long stacked photos]

Answer (score 2):

Put all your images into a folder in the OS.

In Photoshop, choose `File > Automate > Contact Sheet II`

Select the folder of images.

Define the overall document size. (make certain it's tall enough to encompass all the images if you don't want any resizing.)

Set the `Thumbnail` options to have 1 column and rows equal to the number of images.

Hit `OK` and let the automation run.